# what's the condition of session creation

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, cookies

there are two opinion about this.

1. if we disable the cookie,server will create session and rewrite the url like this (http://localhost/login.jsp;jsessionid=07D00E8942B11CA1063735D38B4554DF) to track the request session;
2. if cookie is enable,server will create session and set the response head(Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=07D00E8942B11CA1063735D38B4554DF).

In opinion 1,when the server receive the request, it resolve the jsessionid,and create an session(I'm not sure that this session is created here)

Now ,I enable the cookie,  [and delete all explorer's cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaWM6.jpg) request the url I mentioned .I guess that the session id is passed in the url
.but,the server create a new session and the id is different.

so,I'm confuse that when the server will create a new session.Can we control the behavior of session creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSESSIONID cookie is created/sent when session is created. Session is created when your code calls request.getSession() or request.getSession(true) for the first time.

Put a breakpoint where you write session related code for better idea.

I don't know what case do you want to handle!!  Generally its not good practice to pass JSESSIONID in url. I have passed one time where I want to share session inbetween mobile app and web app.

Comment: thanks for sharing. I want to share session between my app and webview.if we passed a jsessionid in the url , the server couldn't create a session with the id we passed?@bmt

Comment: It should take same session as I did same before. try with `request.getSession(false)`. does it take session?

Comment: I have some new result.if we pass a jsessionid in the url,when we try request.getSession(),this method will return a session if the sessionid is valid or it will return a new session with a different session id;if we try request.getSession(true),it is same as up;otherwise request.getSession(false) will return the session or null.if we want to pass the jsessionid,we must pass it in every link.I  guess that the server would not set-Cookie when we passed jsessionid,because it think that our client is not support cookie.if we don't pass jsessionid,server will set-cookie:jsessionid=sessionid.thanks